How to implement Low Latency, 60 fps video encoding in WebRTC in C# with WebRTC?
Recently, I've been trying to implement a 60 fps low latency screenshare with C# with a library called Sipsorcery. I've tried my best so far to maximize the frames but i only get around 20 fps.
I tried to see whether it was the encoding or the screenshotting. I used Visual Studio CPU usage profiler and saw it was mostly the encoder. Still, I remade the screenshotting function and used SharpDX; I noticed a small increase in performance but nothing near 60 fps That leads me to believe the encoder is the problem. Perhaps it could use FFmpeg or some GPU encoding. Sorry in advance if I put any incorrect details as I'm relatively new to Video Encoding and Decoding.
Heres what I made so far:
//VideoTestPatternSource.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SIPSorceryMedia.Abstractions;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;
using MapFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SIPSorcery.Media
{
    public class VideoSource : IVideoSource, IDisposable
    {
        private const int VIDEO_SAMPLING_RATE = 90000;
        private const int MAXIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 20;
        private const int DEFAULT_FRAMES_PER_SECOND = MAXIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND; // Changed from 30 to 60
        private const int MINIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND = MAXIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND - 5;
        private const int TIMER_DISPOSE_WAIT_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
        private const int VP8_SUGGESTED_FORMAT_ID = 96;
        private const int H264_SUGGESTED_FORMAT_ID = 100;

        public static readonly List<VideoFormat> SupportedFormats = new List<VideoFormat>
        {
            new VideoFormat(VideoCodecsEnum.VP8, VP8_SUGGESTED_FORMAT_ID, VIDEO_SAMPLING_RATE),
            new VideoFormat(VideoCodecsEnum.H264, H264_SUGGESTED_FORMAT_ID, VIDEO_SAMPLING_RATE, "packetization-mode=1")
        };

        private int _frameSpacing;
        private System.Threading.Timer _sendTestPatternTimer;
        private bool _isStarted;
        private bool _isPaused;
        private bool _isClosed;
        private bool _isMaxFrameRate;
        private int _frameCount;
        private SIPSorceryMedia.Abstractions.IVideoEncoder _videoEncoder;
        private MediaFormatManager<VideoFormat> _formatManager;

        public event RawVideoSampleDelegate OnVideoSourceRawSample;

#pragma warning disable CS0067
        public event RawVideoSampleFasterDelegate OnVideoSourceRawSampleFaster;
#pragma warning restore CS0067

        public event EncodedSampleDelegate OnVideoSourceEncodedSample;

        public event SourceErrorDelegate OnVideoSourceError;

        private readonly int _screenWidth;
        private readonly int _screenHeight;

        private Factory1 _factory;
        private Adapter1 _adapter;
        private Device _device;
        private Output1 _output1;
        private OutputDuplication _duplicatedOutput;
        private Texture2D _screenTexture;

        public VideoSource(int width, int height, SIPSorceryMedia.Abstractions.IVideoEncoder encoder = null)
        {
            _screenWidth = width;
            _screenHeight = height;
            if (encoder != null)
            {
                _videoEncoder = encoder;
                _formatManager = new MediaFormatManager<VideoFormat>(SupportedFormats);
            }

            try
            {
                InitializeDirectX();
                _sendTestPatternTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(GeneratePattern, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                _frameSpacing = 1000 / DEFAULT_FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Failed to initialize: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private void InitializeDirectX()
        {
            _factory = new Factory1();
            _adapter = _factory.GetAdapter1(0);
            _device = new Device(_adapter);
            var output = _adapter.GetOutput(0);
            _output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>();

            var textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription
            {
                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
                BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
                Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                Width = _screenWidth,
                Height = _screenHeight,
                OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                MipLevels = 1,
                ArraySize = 1,
                SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging
            };

            _screenTexture = new Texture2D(_device, textureDesc);

            _duplicatedOutput = _output1.DuplicateOutput(_device);
        }

        public void RestrictFormats(Func<VideoFormat, bool> filter) => _formatManager.RestrictFormats(filter);
        public List<VideoFormat> GetVideoSourceFormats() => _formatManager.GetSourceFormats();
        public void SetVideoSourceFormat(VideoFormat videoFormat) => _formatManager.SetSelectedFormat(videoFormat);
        public List<VideoFormat> GetVideoSinkFormats() => _formatManager.GetSourceFormats();
        public void SetVideoSinkFormat(VideoFormat videoFormat) => _formatManager.SetSelectedFormat(videoFormat);

        public void ForceKeyFrame() => _videoEncoder?.ForceKeyFrame();
        public bool HasEncodedVideoSubscribers() => OnVideoSourceEncodedSample != null;

        public void ExternalVideoSourceRawSample(uint durationMilliseconds, int width, int height, byte[] sample, VideoPixelFormatsEnum pixelFormat) =>
            throw new NotImplementedException("The test pattern video source does not offer any encoding services for external sources.");

        public void ExternalVideoSourceRawSampleFaster(uint durationMilliseconds, RawImage rawImage) =>
            throw new NotImplementedException("The test pattern video source does not offer any encoding services for external sources.");

        public Task<bool> InitialiseVideoSourceDevice() =>
            throw new NotImplementedException("The test pattern video source does not use a device.");
        public bool IsVideoSourcePaused() => _isPaused;

        public void SetFrameRate(int framesPerSecond)
        {
            if (framesPerSecond < MINIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND || framesPerSecond > MAXIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Frames per second not in the allowed range of {MINIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND} to {MAXIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND}, ignoring.");
            }
            else
            {
                _frameSpacing = 1000 / framesPerSecond;

                if (_isStarted)
                {
                    _sendTestPatternTimer?.Change(0, _frameSpacing);
                }
            }
        }

        public Task PauseVideo()
        {
            _isPaused = true;
            _sendTestPatternTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task ResumeVideo()
        {
            _isPaused = false;
            _sendTestPatternTimer?.Change(0, _frameSpacing);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StartVideo()
        {
            if (!_isStarted)
            {
                _isStarted = true;
                if (_isMaxFrameRate)
                {
                    GenerateMaxFrames();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _sendTestPatternTimer?.Change(0, _frameSpacing);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The following error occured: " + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task CloseVideo()
        {
            if (!_isClosed)
            {
                _isClosed = true;

                ManualResetEventSlim mre = new ManualResetEventSlim();
                _sendTestPatternTimer?.Dispose(mre.WaitHandle);
                return Task.Run(() => mre.Wait(TIMER_DISPOSE_WAIT_MILLISECONDS));
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void GenerateMaxFrames()
        {
            DateTime lastGenerateTime = DateTime.Now;

            while (!_isClosed && _isMaxFrameRate)
            {
                _frameSpacing = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastGenerateTime).TotalMilliseconds);
                GeneratePattern(null);
                lastGenerateTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        private void GeneratePattern(object state)
        {
            lock (_sendTestPatternTimer)
            {
                if (!_isClosed && (OnVideoSourceRawSample != null || OnVideoSourceEncodedSample != null))
                {
                    _frameCount++;

                    var buffer = Snapshot(_screenWidth, _screenHeight);

                    if (OnVideoSourceRawSample != null)
                    {
                        OnVideoSourceRawSample?.Invoke((uint)_frameSpacing, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, buffer, VideoPixelFormatsEnum.Bgra);
                    }

                    if (_videoEncoder != null && OnVideoSourceEncodedSample != null && !_formatManager.SelectedFormat.IsEmpty())
                    {
                        var encodedBuffer = _videoEncoder.EncodeVideo(_screenWidth, _screenHeight, buffer, VideoPixelFormatsEnum.Bgra, _formatManager.SelectedFormat.Codec);

                        if (encodedBuffer != null)
                        {
                            uint fps = (_frameSpacing > 0) ? 1000 / (uint)_frameSpacing : MAXIMUM_FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
                            uint durationRtpTS = VIDEO_SAMPLING_RATE / fps;
                            OnVideoSourceEncodedSample.Invoke(durationRtpTS, encodedBuffer);
                        }
                    }

                    if (_frameCount == int.MaxValue)
                    {
                        _frameCount = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] Snapshot(int width, int height)
        {
            SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource;
            OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

            try
            {
                _duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(10000, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

                using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
                    _device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, _screenTexture);

                var mapSource = _device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(_screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);

                int stride = width * 4; // 4 bytes per pixel (RGBA)
                byte[] buffer = new byte[stride * height];
                IntPtr sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    // Copy each row from source to buffer
                    Marshal.Copy(sourcePtr, buffer, y * stride, stride);
                    sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch);
                }

                _device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(_screenTexture, 0);

                screenResource.Dispose();
                _duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();

                // Correct pixel inversion (swap R and B channels)
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 4)
                {
                    byte temp = buffer[i];     // Save R
                    buffer[i] = buffer[i + 2]; // Swap R (buffer[i]) with B (buffer[i+2])
                    buffer[i + 2] = temp;      // Swap B with R (saved R)
                                               // buffer[i+1] (G) remains unchanged
                                               // buffer[i+3] (A) remains unchanged
                }

                return buffer;
            }
            catch (SharpDXException e)
            {
                if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                return new byte[width * height * 4];
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _isClosed = true;
            _sendTestPatternTimer?.Dispose();
            _videoEncoder?.Dispose();

            _screenTexture?.Dispose();
            _duplicatedOutput?.Dispose();
            _output1?.Dispose();
            _device?.Dispose();
            _adapter?.Dispose();
            _factory?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

Here's what loads it for reference:
//Program.cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SIPSorcery.Media;
using SIPSorcery.Net;
using SIPSorceryMedia.Encoders;
using SIPSorceryMedia.FFmpeg;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace TESTPATTERNSERVER
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int WEBSOCKET_PORT = 8081;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WebRTC Get Started");

            // Start web socket.
            Console.WriteLine("Starting web socket server...");
            var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(IPAddress.Any, WEBSOCKET_PORT);
            webSocketServer.AddWebSocketService<WebRTCWebSocketPeer>("/", (peer) => peer.CreatePeerConnection = () => CreatePeerConnection());
            webSocketServer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for web socket connections on {webSocketServer.Address}:{webSocketServer.Port}...");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Task<RTCPeerConnection> CreatePeerConnection()
        {
            var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
         
            var testPatternSource = new VideoSource(1920, 1080, new VP8VideoEncoder());
            var videoEndPoint = new SIPSorceryMedia.FFmpeg.FFmpegVideoEndPoint();

            MediaStreamTrack videoTrack = new MediaStreamTrack(videoEndPoint.GetVideoSourceFormats(), MediaStreamStatusEnum.SendOnly);
            pc.addTrack(videoTrack);

            testPatternSource.OnVideoSourceEncodedSample += pc.SendVideo;
            pc.OnVideoFormatsNegotiated += (formats) => testPatternSource.SetVideoSourceFormat(formats.First());

            pc.onconnectionstatechange += async (state) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Peer connection state change to {state}.");

                switch (state)
                {
                    case RTCPeerConnectionState.connected:
                        await testPatternSource.StartVideo();
                        break;
                    case RTCPeerConnectionState.failed:
                        pc.Close("ice disconnection");
                        break;
                    case RTCPeerConnectionState.closed:
                        await testPatternSource.CloseVideo();
                        testPatternSource.Dispose();
                        break;
                }
            };

            return Task.FromResult(pc);
        }
    }
}

Thanks in advance!

I believe the only way this is possible is to use the hardware codec available on the GPU, which can use your screen texture directly as a frame source, and can give you encoded streams in low latency with best efficiency.  NVIDIA has samples in their SDK for NVENC.  For Intel, check out QuickSync.  I'm not familiar with what to use in AMD land.

The FFmpeg implementation definitely worked. I got 50 to 60 frames with h264 encoding. FFmpeg is only being used as a encoder though. I still could improve the snapshotting method. Thanks for everyone's help!

Great!! Instead of thanking the person like this though, it's better to simply mark the answer as correct and thank them in the comments (as you've already done). Doing this just clutters things even if it's with a good intentions!

This is mostly a discussion about video codecs for low latency use, since I'm not familiar with WebRTC.
Low latency is very difficult to combine with high efficiency. High efficiency video codecs like h264, VP8 etc use motion vectors and many other tricks to exploit the frame to frame similarity, called Predicted frames. But this require a buffer of frames to work on. This also requires each and every frame to arrive intact and in order. So any lost packets will need to be resent, increasing latency. There will also be fully encoded frames every now and then, and this can cause a stutter due to the uneven frame size.
So the simplest option to get low latency is to just skip all the predictive frame stuff and encode each frame as a full frame. I.e. MJPEG or equivalent. Ideally using a high performance library for encoding/decoding. This allow you to drop frames if there is packet loss, since each frame is independent.
There are certainly better options, this post dives in to various h264 settings that should help reduce latency. But h264 is a lot more complex than jpeg, so may not perform as well unless you can use a hardware encoder.
But most video codecs, as well as Jpeg, are tuned for real world images. If you intend to share videos of desktop applications there are likely specialized encodings that handle things like text and large uniform areas better. But the best encoders are likely proprietary, or under patent, since there is a fair bit of money in being able to efficiently stream video.

I looked a little more into it and found the repo has an extension called SIPSorceryMedia.FFmpeg. Would FFmpeg support fast and better encoding overall?I'm not to sure how to implement it into my program so any tips on that would help to. Thanks for you help though.

@Developer FFmpeg should have a wide variety of encoders/decoders, but I think it is more intended for video encoding than low latency real time streaming. It would most likely work if you configure it well it, but it would depend on on your specific requirements. I'm fairly sure software like TeamViewer has spent a lot of time and money on their encoder.
